# C / Python WinPCap Translation

Tags: python, c, python-3.x, packet-capture, winpcap

Sorry, this will be a very simple question for most of you.

I'm trying to convert some of the code from [here](https://www.winpcap.org/docs/docs_40_2/html/group__wpcap__tut6.html) into Python (3.4) as I don't know C. That's primarily the basis of this issue. While I have created the Python data structures according to the link:

```
from ctypes import *
u_short = c_ushort
u_char = c_ubyte
u_int = c_int

class ip_address(Structure):
    _fields=[("byte1",u_char),
             ("byte2",u_char),
             ("byte3",u_char),
             ("byte4",u_char)]

class ip_header(Structure):
    _fields=[("ver_ihl",u_char),
             ("tos",u_char),
             ("tlen",u_short),
             ("identification",u_short),
             ("flags_fo",u_short),
             ("ttl",u_char),
             ("proto",u_char),
             ("crc",u_short),
             ("saddr",ip_address),
             ("daddr",ip_address),
             ("op_pad",u_int)]

class udp_header(Structure):
    _fields=[("sport",u_short),
             ("dport",u_short),
             ("len",u_short),
             ("crc",u_short)]

class data(Structure):
    _fields[("data",c_char_p)]
```

I don't know enough about C to convert the following code in Python:

```
ip_header *ih;
udp_header *uh;
u_int ip_len;
u_short sport,dport;

/* retrieve the position of the ip header */
ih = (ip_header *) (pkt_data +
    14); //length of ethernet header

/* retrieve the position of the udp header */
ip_len = (ih->ver_ihl & 0xf) * 4;
uh = (udp_header *) ((u_char*)ih + ip_len);

/* convert from network byte order to host byte order */
sport = ntohs( uh->sport );
dport = ntohs( uh->dport );

/* print ip addresses and udp ports */
printf("%d.%d.%d.%d.%d -> %d.%d.%d.%d.%d\n",
    ih->saddr.byte1,
    ih->saddr.byte2,
    ih->saddr.byte3,
    ih->saddr.byte4,
    sport,
    ih->daddr.byte1,
    ih->daddr.byte2,
    ih->daddr.byte3,
    ih->daddr.byte4,
    dport);
```

I know that I need to change the "ih->ver_ihl" to "ih.ver_ihl" however I don't understand the rest. If I understand UDP packets correctly, the next section of the packet will be Data. I would also like to extract that from the packet if possible.

Thanks in advance for any help you can provide

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some notes:

- For ctypes structures, you must use `_fields_` not `_fields`.
- As a rule of thumb, I tend to use [Flake8](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/flake8) on my code, even on snippets.

**Test**

I tested my code on an NTP packet, as NTP is over UDP, to see if everything was correct.

- Go to [Wireshark wiki: NTP](http://wiki.wireshark.org/NTP)
- Download first example capture ( [SampleCaptures/NTP_sync.pcap](http://wiki.wireshark.org/SampleCaptures?action=AttachFile&do=get&target=NTP_sync.pcap) )
- Load pcap into wireshark > select first packet > go to "View " > 
  ensure "Packet details" is cheked.
- click on packet details window, Frame 1, (should read "Frame 1: 75 bytes on wire (600 bits), 75 bytes captured (600 bits)" > right click > "export selected packet bytes".

Pass the saved file to the following script.

**Output**

`192.168.50.50:1026 -> 192.168.0.1:53`

This is correct, according to wireshark.

**Code**

```
#!/usr/local/bin/python3
# -*- coding: utf8 -*-

import sys
import ctypes
import socket

from ctypes import *
u_short = c_ushort
u_char = c_ubyte
u_int = c_int


class ip_address(Structure):
    _fields_ = [("byte1", u_char),
                ("byte2", u_char),
                ("byte3", u_char),
                ("byte4", u_char)]


class ip_header(BigEndianStructure):
    _fields_ = [("ver_ihl", u_char),
                ("tos", u_char),
                ("tlen", u_short),
                ("identification", u_short),
                ("flags_fo", u_short),
                ("ttl", u_char),
                ("proto", u_char),
                ("crc", u_short),
                ("saddr", ip_address),
                ("daddr", ip_address),
                ("op_pad", u_int)]


class udp_header(BigEndianStructure):
    _fields_ = [("sport", u_short),
                ("dport", u_short),
                ("len", u_short),
                ("crc", u_short)]


def packet_handler(pkt_data):

    # cast pkt_data to void so we can do some pointer arithmetic
    v_pkt_data = ctypes.cast(pkt_data, ctypes.c_void_p)

    # retrieve the position of the ip header
    v_ip_header = ctypes.c_void_p(v_pkt_data.value + 14)
    pih = ctypes.cast(v_ip_header, ctypes.POINTER(ip_header))
    ih = pih.contents

    # retrieve the position of the udp header
    ip_len = (ih.ver_ihl & 0xf) * 4
    uh = ctypes.cast(ctypes.cast(pih, ctypes.c_void_p).value + ip_len,
                     ctypes.POINTER(udp_header)).contents

    # convert from network byte order to host byte order
    sport = socket.ntohs(uh.sport)
    dport = socket.ntohs(uh.dport)

    print("{}.{}.{}.{}:{} -> {}.{}.{}.{}:{}".format(
        ih.saddr.byte1, ih.saddr.byte2, ih.saddr.byte3, ih.saddr.byte4, sport,
        ih.daddr.byte1, ih.daddr.byte2, ih.daddr.byte3, ih.daddr.byte4, dport))

    # Extracting data
    #

    # data offset from ip header start
    data_offset = ip_len + ctypes.sizeof(udp_header)
    # data length
    data_len = ih.tlen - ip_len - ctypes.sizeof(udp_header)
    # get data
    arr_type = (ctypes.c_uint8 * data_len)
    data = arr_type.from_address(v_ip_header.value + data_offset)

    print(data[0:data_len])

    # note: same thing could be achieved from pkt_data
    print(pkt_data[14+data_offset:14+data_offset+data_len])


def main(packet_file):
    with open(packet_file, "rb") as fd:
        data = fd.read()

    # create ctypes.c_char_array
    pkt_data = ctypes.c_buffer(data)
    packet_handler(pkt_data)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    if len(sys.argv) == 2:
        main(sys.argv[1])
```

Comment: I also got the data extraction part working using a constant UDP header length of 8. Is there a way to do `(ih.ver_ihl & 0xf) * 4` with the `uh`?

Comment: @Apples292 The data payload size must be calculated from the IP header (`ih.tlen` is the size of IP header + UDP  header + payload) as the UDP header doesn't carry any size. Oh, BTW, while checking my code I saw that structures must inherit from `BigEndianStructure` and not from `Structure` otherwise the endianess is wrong and thus you get wrong results while calculating data size. I edited my code above with 2 ways to get data payload and the new structures.

Comment: Awesome, this all works exactly how I envisioned! Thanks